# How to count the number of rows in a table using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I have a table with X rows in an HTML web page. How do I count the number of rows using Selenium Java and CSS or XPath expressions?

Example of my table:

```
<tbody id="MyTableId">
<tr> First Data row</tr>
<tr> 2nd Data row</tr>
<tr> 3rd Data row<tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: List<WebElement> myTableRows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#MyTableId tr"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution :

```
List<WebElement> rowCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@id='MyTableId']/tbody/tr"));
System.out.println("Num rows: " + rowCount .size());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the below lines without xpath :

```
 WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("MyTableId"));

 int numberOfRows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr")).size();

 System.out.println("table row count : "+numberOfRows);
```